# Cauchy integral formula statement confusion

Tags: complex-analysis

From the wiki page we have the thoerem statement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

It states that for any $a$ on the interior of the disc, the formula holds. I can't see a problem if $a$ was outside the interior, or if $a$ was on the boundary. Could someone explain why is it oly the interior.

Comment: If $a$ is outside, the integral on the right is zero because the integrand is analytic inside the disc, using Cauchy's theorem. On the boundary, you have problems with the convergence of the integral.

Comment: @Chappers perhaps you should just go and make that an answer? That is the answer. There's not a lot more to say

Comment: @mixedmath Okay, will do. You're right that that's basically it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ is outside, the integral on the right is zero because the integrand is analytic inside the disc, using Cauchy's theorem. On the boundary, you have problems with the convergence of the integral: since $f$ is continuous, you have a section where the integral looks like
$$ \int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon} \frac{dx}{x}, $$
which doesn't exist.

Comment: brilliant thank you very much